# I am having trouble with wide beam of my ultrasonic sensor

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor, ultrasound, beamforming

[image]I need to measure and detect a gap between two objects.  I have an MB7062 (maxbotix) ultrasonic sonar sensor. Due to the wide beam of the sensor (FOV in distance of 2m is about 30cm from the center each side, that means totally 60cm,) the sensor cannot identify the gap. Is there any way to narrow its FOV so that it detects the gap?

This is the link to datasheet:
http://www.warf.com/download/6439_4951_1.pdf

Sensor pin2 output:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a data sheet for the sensor AND indicate which circuit you are using to interface to it.

Comment: Hi! Welcome here, do you mean [this](https://maxbotix.com/products/mb7062) sensor?

I mean, looking at the directivity, this is an extremely narrow beam; making it any narrower will be hard as hell. What makes you thing the width of the beam is what stops it from identifying the gap? Is there something else in the beam, or how does that happen?

Comment: Can you comment on why you think that a overly wide beam is the problem? I don't understand.

Comment: @Andyaka The datasheet is provided, and I am only using a serial connection and observe the output in a GUI in python

Comment: Which housing option do you have?

Comment: @MarcusMüller when I move the sensor throughout the two objects with 20cm gap in between it only measures the distance to the objects and the gap doesn't lead to an increase in the distance

Comment: The way you make a "beam" like that narrower is to make the transducer bigger (bigger aperture with the same wavelength == narrower beam).  You could also try a parabolic reflector, and mount your transducer at the focus.

Comment: Active sensors usually have dead zone. Than transducer emmits it can not receive. And also some switching process from transmitting to receiving takes time. The minimum "0" is nonsense.

Comment: @MobinMadani thansk! Now I must admit I can't really imagine the geometry of your measurement problem. Do you think you could make a drawing (e.g. on paper, taking a photo with your phone or such?) that shows where the two objects are, what gap you're referring to, and where the sensor is, and how it is oriented? This seems to be a very interesting measurement problem. Do you happen to have an oscilloscope which you could attach to your device's pin 2?

Comment: @datenheim actually it has a nut and a thread

Comment: @user263983 Of course, the minimum range that the sensor works correctly is about 20cm, but for now this is not the case.

Comment: You are moving your sensor across the two objects and across the gap, right?  Does your sensor allow you to measure the amplitude of the refection?  If so, the you could look for the minimum in the returned signal as the sensor moves across the gap.

Comment: You did not mention about objects, size, material, etc. If beam directed not exactly 90° reflection from sidewalls may reflect and create interference. Your case is complicated and with information, you provided, no conclusion can be made.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sure, the info is provided

Comment: @MobinMadani thank you very much! So, according to the datasheet (page 2, description of "Pin 2"), these pulses should, since your object is 2 m away, be 58 µs/cm · 200 cm = 11.6 ms wide; but they're not?

Comment: @user263983 Objects are 2 cubes with 2 meter width, made of iron and the sensor is 90°. Moreover I move the sensor at speed of about 2.5 m/s

Comment: **MB7062** has internal *"noise-reduction"*. Multiple measurements are compared in an attempt to eliminate "false" readings. Since OP's intention is to detect **an absence** of a return echo, the desired output (no pulse) *might be rejected*, favoring the "wall" detection - its software may be working against you. High acoustic power may be working against you as well.

Comment: @glen_geek Thanks for your answer. But when it sees the gap there is a surface in the other side that reflects the echo and the pulse exists. The sensor should return a distance that is higher than previous I believe.

Comment: In closed space a lot of reflections. Ekcept the main beam side beams are exist too. That a wrong type of sensor for the task.

Answer (score 3):

The sensor operates at 42KHz.  With speed of sound ~330m/s this gives a wavelength of around 8mm.

The [Rayleigh Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_resolution) allows us to approximate the imaging resolution of a system based on the diffraction limit.  It is normally stated in terms of angular resolution, but
a good approximation of the limit is

**Resolution = Wavelength * Distance / Sensor Diameter**

The source size appears to be about 25mm (based on physical dimensions in the datasheet), so at 2000mm distance, that sets a diffraction limit of ~80 wavelengths, or 640mm. This matches the observed behavior.

To get a resolution down to ~100mm @ 2m, would require a source of ~150mm in diameter.  This might be possible to approximate with a custom elliptical horn (for focus at 2m), but I'm guessing this doesn't match you overall system requirements...